# What is the use of npm.js in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, npm

What is the meaning of `npm.js` and included file.

```
require('../../js/transition.js')
require('../../js/alert.js')
require('../../js/button.js')
require('../../js/carousel.js')
require('../../js/collapse.js')
require('../../js/dropdown.js')
require('../../js/modal.js')
require('../../js/tooltip.js')
require('../../js/popover.js')
require('../../js/scrollspy.js')
require('../../js/tab.js')
require('../../js/affix.js')
```

Do I need to include the files or download them?